# Curses Command Line Application in Python

Tags: python, console, curses

I'm writing a command line console application that receives input from user and interprets it as a command and performs the necessary action (like metasploit console). My application is already done and ready to go but my problem is I implemented it with `input()` function which does not handle arrow keys. If I mistype something and not notice it, I have to delete every character back to that typo and retype the rest of the command. I want to implement it in a way that would accept arrow keys to navigate around the characters. Is there anyone who knows how to do that?

(As I specified above, I'm trying to find a way to do that with curses library. But any other library that can do what I need would be highly appreciated)

Code example:

```
while True:
    command = input("command >")

    if command == "say_hello":
        print("Hello")
    elif command == "exit":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Undefined command")
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I just edited the post and included the code. But instead of input(), I want to use something else that implements arrow key handling as I described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Python's built-in [cmd library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html). You would sub-class `cmd.Cmd` and then write `do_*` methods for each of the commands you'd like recognized:

```
import cmd

class SimpleAppShell(cmd.Cmd):
    """A simple example of Python's Cmd library."""
    
    prompt = "command > "

    def do_say_hello(self, arg):
        print("Hello")

    def do_exit(self, arg):
        print("Goodbye")
        exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleAppShell().cmdloop()
```

Because `cmd.Cmd` uses by default the [readline library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) (the Python interface to [GNU Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline)), you'll get the ability to move the cursor around and edit the line input by default, as well as a whole bunch of other helpful behavior out-of-the-box. See [this PyMOTW post](https://pymotw.com/2/cmd/) for more info and examples.